# Assembler Following Code Generation?

Tags: compiler-construction, nasm

I recently asked [a question on *Software Engineering*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369842/assemblers-used-during-the-development-of-a-programming-language), but was met with far too many downvotes for a remarkably serious question. As such, I will attempt to rephrase the question a slight bit to make it suited for *Stack Overflow*.

**For the development of a programming language, would it be viable to use the [*NASM* assembler](https://www.nasm.us/) to assemble the resulting assembly code, following the code generation stage in the compiler?**

If the answer to that question is *no*, I would like to ask what should (by convention) be used instead. Some standard bundled up with the current operating system? Some other assembler?

I am aware of *LLVM*, and how it is normally used for modern compiler creation. The reason I've chosen not to use that is because *I want a hands on experience developing my own compiler*.

Comment: Most Unix-like systems will have an assembler available as `as` somewhere in the PATH (usually `/usr/bin`). On Linux that's usually the GNU assembler, which is part of the GNU binutils package. On OSX it's Apple's fork of the GNU assembler. On Windows there is no pre-installed assembler, but MinGW at least ships with the GNU assembler as well. So that seems a reasonable target (which isn't to say that targetting NASM isn't also viable - I can't really speak to that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a viable solution and one I used myself in the very early stages of a language development project.

Pros: Free, multi-platform
Cons: It's assembler so knowing the variations of ABI is a requirement of your code.

As time went on we eventually moved to generating LLVM-IR to leverage it's optimization and multi-architecture targeting capabilities.